# Nginx - Serving static files from multiple servers using sub-uri's

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use nginx to host multiple web servers using sub-uri's such that I can have one on `/app1` and another on `/app2`.

Each web app, when run alone responds to `/` with an `index.html` page that references a `/js/application.js` file.

```
# Directory structure
app
app/index.html
app/js
app/js/application.js
```

I currently am able to configure nginx to route requests to `/app1` and `/app2` to the correct app, but the issue I have now is that each is serving up a page that makes a request to `/js/application.js`. I want to have each app route their requests for that file to the appropriate app (e.g. `/js/application.js` from app 1 will route to `/app1/js/application.js`).

Is there some way to do this with nginx? I notice that the `Referer` request header has something along the lines of `Referer: "http://my-ip-address/app1"`. Is there anyway to switch on this when routing requests?

EDIT:

Mine is a little different as things aren't named app1/app2, but here's the gist of what my config file looks like:

```
servers {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /app1 {
    rewrite /app1(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:3000
  }

  location /app2 {
    rewrite /app2(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:3001
  }

  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: Please show the nginx config you currently have

Comment: added my nginx config

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$http_referer` variable in the nginx configuration